# Javascript eval questions

Tags: javascript

I see following code and would like to know what it is doing.
It is converting eval result to object?

```
eval("Function here")("Object here");
```

I have another question. Does eval work as reflection? It loads to memory every time this code is called and ends up with memory leak?

Comment: In my Node console it's just triggering: *SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier*

Comment: try it, eval(console.log)({y:1})

Comment: You show neither function nor object. How should we tell you, what's going on there? And there's the "old" saying: eval is evil. Please do not use it.

Answer (score 2):

Adding in the (Object Here) part makes whatever object is passed  a parameter of the function.

And no, eval() does not show up in the reflection - only the evaluated code does.

Example

```js
var test_object = "testing!";

console.log("part 1:");
// evaluates whatever is inside of eval();
eval(function(param) {
  console.log(param);
})(test_object);

// result is 'testing!'

// now to try to use reflection on eval

var go = eval(function(param) {
  console.log(param)
});

console.log("part 2:");
console.log(go);

//result does not include eval()
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems like this answered my questions!

Answer (score 0):

[eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) tries to evaluate the string given as a parameter as javascript code, then tries to run the code.

In your case the eval function will create the method "function here", then call it using "object here" as parameter

As a side node, I recommend not using `eval` if what you need to do can be done in any other, as eval may cause security issues. Here's some documentation about [How evil is eval](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's eval function is a way of running a string as if it were code.

For example:

```
eval("(function func1(p) {console.log('p: ' + p);})")("test");
```

is basically the same as

```
(function func2(p) {
  console.log('p: ' + p);
})("test");
```

which is basically the same as

```
function func3(p) {
  console.log('p: ' + p);
}
func3("test");
```